# Responsive media query not working in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, frameworks, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using **Media Queries** given bellow for responsive in Thesis framework in wordpress. But it is not working. I also get help from these stackoverflow answers but still not working.

[Responsive site works on desktop but not mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944131/responsive-site-works-on-desktop-but-not-mobile)

[responsive media query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538717/responsive-media-query-not-working)

When I check this query at this http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lvticketattorney.com%2F it is working. But when I check it at mobile device it is not working.

**Media Queries**

```
@media (max-width: 569px) {
    .menu a{font-size:10px;}
    .list-left, .list-right{ width:100%; float:left !important;}
    .custom #header{ background-size:95%;}
}
@media (max-width: 415px) {
    .menu{ border:0 !important;}
    .menu li{ width:95%; border-bottom:solid 2px #fff;}
    .menu .current a{ border:solid 1px #000;}
    #content_box #content{ width:100%;}
    #content_box #sidebars{ width:100%;}
    .teaser_right, .teaser{ float:left; width:90%;}
    .gform_wrapper{ width:100%;}
    #attachment_661{ width:100% !important;}
    .gform_footer{ width:50%; }
    }
@media (max-width: 385px) {
    .format_text h1{ font-size:18px;}
    .custom #header{ height:90px;} 
    #box{ width:95%;}
    #box img{ height:auto;}
    .menu{ margin-top:-10px; border-top:solid 1px #000;}
    .format_text p span{ font-size:14px !important;}
    .headline_area h1, .headline_area h2, #archive_intro h1{ font-size:18px;}
    .wp-image-167, .wp-image-207{ width:100px;}
    }
```

Comment: which mobile device?  sometimes in responsive you have to do little hacks here and there for particular types of devices (e.g. ios vs android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this media query `@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) { ---- Style--- }`. Now it is working. `only screen and` was missing.